# How do you select multiple objects within a table cell?

Tags: adobe-indesign, selections

In indesign you can select multiple objects by pressing shift and selecting the objects you want to edit, however this doesn't work when the objects are pasted within the cell of a table. How do I select multiple objects when they are within a table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to have multiple objects inside a table cell is to have them as inline objects inside text. You cannot select multiple inline objects by selecting them with shift+click; they are considered "characters", and so you must use the regular text selection methods: place your text cursor before the first object, hold down shift, and move right.

This selects the object *containers*, not the objects themself. If you need to do something with the objects (for example, give them an Object Style), there is no alternative but to click and change them one by one.